# Mongo 3.2 $lookup with $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document structure in mongo 3.2

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c16b2e5ef0616776e63b401"),
"brands" : [ ],
"vendors" : [ ],
"categories" : [ ],
"roles" : [
    ObjectId("5c16b2e4ef0616776e63b400")
],
"userId" : ObjectId("5bf2e384186cee7f5b42e776"),
"tenantId" : "2100",
"status" : "Active",
"__v" : 0
}
```

I am using $lookup along with $group to get the actual roles _id and name from roles collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c10145b385a1c52ba0494c9"),
    "permissions" : [
        "orders:view",
        "orders:export",
        "order:view",
        "order:edit"
    ],
    "name" : "Orders Management",
    "tenantId" : "1400",
    "__v" : 2
}
```

The query I use, but `roles` array always coming empty, what I am doing wrong ?

```
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'userId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'user',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'roles',
          localField: 'roles',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'roles',
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          id: '$_id',
          status: 1,
          userId: 1,
          tenantId: 1,
          'user.email': 1,
          'user.username': 1,
          'roles._id': 1,
          'roles.name': 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$user',
      }
```

Comment: the roles document you are looking for really exists? at least your example has different id's

Comment: I did not think to provide real data :) just example. Yes it does exist.

Comment: Probably your collection name is incorrect `from: "roles"`

Comment: I found it works Okay in 3.6 but not in 3.2